# vectortiles: change style of basemap instead of data

Tags: leaflet, layers, style, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using *Mapbox-GL-Leaflet* bindings on *Leaflet* to style my vector tiles. I'd now allow the user to switch a style using *Leaflet* control.

The easiest way would be to use *LayerControl* for this. Since the basemap is always the same data, just the style changes. But this change of basemaps would remove the old data and reload the same data. I don't know if you can detect this change (plus the delay of *Mapbox-GL-Leaflet*) on slower systems.

Is there a way to make the *LayerControl* not reload the data, but just change the style?